# How to use data binding to set layout_centerVertical in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-databinding

Say I have view that might be center vertical aligned in `RelativeLayout`. I want to use data binding to achieve this.

```
android:layout_centerVertical="@{data.shouldCenter ? true : false}"
```

I'm getting `data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. center is missing it ****\ data binding error ****` using the above. How should I get this to work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="data"
            type="com.test.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.title}"
            android:layout_centerVertical="@{data.shouldCenter ? true : false}"
            android:textColor="@{data.titleTextColor}"
            android:visibility="@{data.title != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginSmall"
            android:text="@{data.message}"
            android:visibility="@{data.message != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Have you import above "data" variable in XML? Can you please paste your xml sample for more clarity?

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: edited, but what really breaks is the initial line I posted.

Comment: Have you try with answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution, that is using `BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter(" android:layout_centerVertical")
public static void setCenterVertical(View view, boolean isCenterVertical) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,
            isCenterVertical ? RelativeLayout.TRUE : 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

and using it as:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.title}"
            android:layout_centerVertical="@{data.shouldCenter}"
            android:textColor="@{data.titleTextColor}"
            android:visibility="@{data.title != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

hope this helps

Comment: ideally I wanted to minimize java code, but I can't seem to find any other solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to call method. Don't use direct variable in databinding. So you have to replace your code with below lines.

```
 android:layout_centerVertical="@{data.shouldCenter() ? true : false}"
```

and you have to create getter method on your model like below :

```
boolean shouldCenter;

public boolean shouldCenter() {
    return shouldCenter;
}
```

It will works for me. Check it and tell if it will not works !

Comment: compiler gives me `msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_centerVertical' with parameter type boolean on android.widget.TextView.`

Comment: wait i will check it and will tell you soon